# How to parse json file into unix script

Tags: json, shell, unix, scripting

I have a json file and I want to read it into unix shell script, how can we achieve it?

I know how to pass it in python, but having idea about passing in shell.

sample code:

```
import json
import sys
from pprint import pprint

jdata = open(sys.argv[1])

data = json.load(jdata)
```

Comment: You cannot parse JSON data in bash, because the result doesn't make sense: bash doesn't have deep structures (i.e. bash array can't contain other arrays, for example). You can get at specific pieces of information inside the JSON by using `jq` or `ruby` or `python`, for example.

Comment: So I need to load json into python, then filter required data and pass them as args to shell script.

Comment: I don't know. You haven't told us the scenario you have, aside from the impossible thing the question literally asks.

Comment: try to use `jq`!!!

Comment: Scenario is need to get few parameters inside json file and use them inside shell script.

Comment: jq related lib are not available in our env